# Wi-Fi doesn't work at university

Tags: networking, wireless

I currently have an issue with my Wi-Fi adapter.

My Wi-Fi works fine at home, no issues there. However, at university, I can connect but when I try to load a page through Chrome it just says 'Resolving host' until the page gives an error.

I'm not sure how this happens. I've attached a log from the wireless-info tool.
Thank you!
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23940120/

EDIT: It used to work fine until a few days ago. Just stopped working then.

Comment: University networks usually have some kind of authentication. If you're using eduroam, right click on the network connections icon in the top bar, > "edit connections", find the wifi network in the list and click "edit", and then fill in your details in the security tab. Look here too: [Can't access Eduroam wireless internet connection SETTINGS (Linux Mint 17)](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/215870)

Comment: I've done all the right settings as provided by my university.

Comment: That is the first time i see that: `wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 0 dBm as advertised by <MAC 'KDG_Student' [AC1]>` it seems that your wifi device automatically limit your output power to 0dBm... You can't reach the AP. You could try to rise your txpower manually. With `sudo iwconfig <interface> txpower 20` you should have 20dBm output power.

Comment: Also to add to kcdtv's comment, in that network configuration window, where you filled in the details provided by your uni, on the ipv4 settings tab, make sure it's set to automatic (dhcp).

Comment: Sorry for never replying, but this solution worked. Thanks!